# Can an ng-content be used inside of an ngFor?

Tags: angular

We'd like to put a `ng-content` inside of an `*ngFor` and then specify the contents of the `ng-content` when the component containing the ngFor is used. Is it possible?

```
<li *ngFor="let data of dataSource">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</li>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ypueaoaX43kc1HRm7q3f?p=preview)

Comment: Have the same issue. Any solution for Angular 4?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible but probably doesn't produce the desired result. Children passed by the parent can only projected once (no matter how many `<ng-content>` are there. If the `<ng-content>` elements don't select specific and different parts of the passed children using the `select` attribute, then everything is projected to the first `<ng-content>` with the default selector (none).

To make this work you probably want a custom `ngFor` that repeats the content passed to `<ng-content>`.

[`NgFor`s `ngForTemplate`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) might help in your use case.

See also [Angular2 child component as data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755844/angular2-child-component-as-data/36760027#36760027)

Comment: Can you share a small example of how should be implemented?

Comment: Look for `ngTemplateOutlet` or `ngForTemplate`. There are several answers.

Comment: really helpful (-_-)

Answer (score 37):

It is possible, but it will not give you the proper result. What you want can be achieved using `ng-template` and `TemplateRef`.

I have made a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-inside-ngfor?file=src/app/ngx-datagrid/ngx-datagrid.component.ts) that might help you.

child.component.html

```
<li *ngFor="let rowDetail of dataSource">
  <ng-container
     *ngIf="headerTemplateRef"
     [ngTemplateOutlet]="headerTemplateRef"
     [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit:rowDetail}"
  >
  </ng-container>
</li>
```

child.component.ts

```
@ContentChild('header',{static: false}) headerTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

parent.component.html

```
<child-app [data]="data"> 
    <ng-template let-rowDetail #header>
        <div style="padding-left:35px;">
            <div>{{rowDetail.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</child-app>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly the solution I was looking for, would you mind to explain how all this works?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is best solution I've seen so far. I wanted to give default template, if no content provided by the parent.

Comment: U mentioned "but it will not give you the proper result.". Please also tell us the caveats of your answer, if applicable