# Angular2 child component as data

Tags: angular

Let's say I have two components: `parent` and `child`. The HTML would look like this:

```
<parent title="Welcome">
    <child name="Chris">Blue Team</child>
    <child name="Tom">Red Team</child>
</parent>
```

The final output would look like:

```
<h1>Welcome</h2>
<ul>
    <li><b>Chris</b> is on the Blue Team</li>
    <li><b>Tom</b> is on the Red Team</li>
</ul>
```

The parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  directives: [ChildComponent], // needed?
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <ul>
       <li *ngFor="#child of children()">{{child.content}}<li>
    </ul>`
})
export class ParentComponent {

    @Input() title;

    children() {
        // how?
    }

}
```

How do I access the child components from within the parent and get their content?

Also, I don't want the children to be automatically rendered. Depending on some conditions I may choose not to show certain children.

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to achive that, but it is just too much work, you can get very close example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730210/binding-events-when-using-a-ngfortemplate-in-angular-2/36732644?noredirect=1#comment61052816_36732644)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**`<ng-content>`**

For projecting content to an element (transclusion) you would need the `<ng-content>` element like

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  directives: [ChildComponent], // needed?
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <ul>
       <li *ngFor="letchild of children()">
         <ng-content></ng-content>
       </li>
    </ul>`
})
```

**`<ng-content select="xxx">`**

but that won't work for your use case because `<ng-content>` doesn't produce content, it only projects it (works as a placehoder where children are displayed within your components template.

Even though `*ngFor` would produce 3 `<ng-content>` elements, the children would only be displayed once in the first `<ng-content>` element.

`<ng-content>` allows to use selectors like

```ts
<ng-content select="[name=Chris]"></ng-content>
```

where a template like

```ts
<ul>
   <li>
     <ng-content select="[name=Chris]"></ng-content>
   </li>
</ul>`
```

would result in

```ts
<h1>Welcome</h2>
<ul>
    <li><b>Chris</b> is on the Blue Team</li>
</ul>
```

A more flexible and powerful approach explained in [Binding events when using a ngForTemplate in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730210/binding-events-when-using-a-ngfortemplate-in-angular-2/36732644) (from @kemsky s comment)

**`<template>`, `@ViewChildren()`, and `*ngForTemplate`**

If you wrap the children in `<template>` tags you can access them using `@ContentChildren()` and insert them using `*ngFor` and `*ngForTemplate`.

I am using a little hack here with the inner `*ngFor`. There is a better approach work in progress (`ngTemplateOutlet` https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8021 already merged)

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let child of templates">
         <!-- with [child] we make the single element work with 
              *ngFor because it only works with arrays -->
         <span *ngFor="let t of [child]" *ngForTemplate="child"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div>children:{{children}}</div>
    <div>templates:{{templates}}</div>
    `
})
export class ParentComponent {

  @Input() title;
  @ContentChildren(TemplateRef) templates;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [ParentComponent],
    template: `
    <h1>Hello</h1>
<parent title="Welcome">
  <template><child name="Chris">Blue Team</child></template>
  <template><child name="Tom">Red Team</child></template>
</parent>    
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/pp67zz?p=preview)

See also [How to repeat a piece of HTML multiple times without ngFor and without another @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676593/how-to-repeat-a-piece-of-html-multiple-times-without-ngfor-and-without-anoher-c/37676946#37676946) for more `ngTemplateOutlet` Plunker examples.

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

Answer (score 0):

The children would only be displayed once in the last `<ng-content>`.