# Angular 2 bind transcluded content to loop variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to bind transcluded content to a variable inside of a component loop but I'm unable to do so.

I've looked at the PrimeNG's `dropdown`component and they use the `template` tag along with `let-car` to bind to the `car` variable of the loop.

However when I try this I can't even get the content to transclude. What is the correct way of achieving this?

Attempts:

```
<!-- Obviously not gonna work -->
<comp>
  <span>{{option.name}}, {{option.type}}</span>
</comp>

<!-- Thought this would work but it doesn't, in odd scenarios I get the last element of the loop to transclude content and bind correctly. -->
<comp>
  <template let-option>
    <span>{{option.name}}, {{option.type}}</span>
  </template>
</comp>
```

In component:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let option of options">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Simple plunkr of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://plnkr.co/edit/6SS03fuXmbvJB4nmf1AO?p=preview

Comment: found a full example in the comments

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update Angular 6**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`
`template` should be `ng-template`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**Original**

You can get the template reference and add it using for example `ngTemplateOutlet` or `ngForTemplate` to get the template content added to the DOM. With `ngTemplateOutlet` you can provide your own context that you then can access with template variables as you tried.

```
class CompComponent {
  context = {option: 'some option'};
  constructor(private templateRef:TemplateRef){}
}
```

```
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef" [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: context}"></ng-template>
```

I think in **newer versions** this needs to be

```
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: context}"></ng-template>
```

(but haven't yet verified)

See also

- [How to repeat a piece of HTML multiple times without ngFor and without another @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676593/how-to-repeat-a-piece-of-html-multiple-times-without-ngfor-and-without-anoher-c/37676946#37676946)
- [Angular2 child component as data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755844/angular2-child-component-as-data/36760027#36760027)

Comment: What exactly is `context` supposed to be?

Comment: Might be something like "this" for that templateRef. I'm just guessing (: I'm looking into this pattern myself.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you explain in more detail how templateRef (and `let-something` attribute) work, if you have time? Docs are terrible (;

Comment: Also get `No provider for TemplateRef`, nvm I'm stupid.

Comment: As far as I remember from when I last tried, `[ngOutletContext]="context"` is what is made available as context to the template. With `<template let-option>` you make the `option` property of `context` availabe to the template.

Comment: `$implicit` is implicitly available and holds the whole `context` (just from the top of my head). I have to check, I'm sure I have posted some answer where this is actually used.

Comment: Ok, but why am I getting `No provider for TemplateRef` though? I don't get it, I've injected it into the component..

Comment: Might be that `<template let-option>` needs to be `<template let-option="option">`. Can you create a Plunker that demonstrates what exactly you try to accomplish. This would make it easier to investigate and test.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're exactly doing from the few fragments. A Plunker would be really helpful.

Comment: This is working https://plnkr.co/edit/oxO1ouwc2xzTN0R7pMgD?p=preview I don't know why injecting doesn't work and I have yet to figure out how `$implicit` can be used.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll go with what's working for now. Let me know if you manage to figure the other things out.

Comment: `$implicit` isn't necessary but it might property access of the context easier. I'll add a comment when I know more.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/JuwbvVe5sBGMI9Xm2DsS?p=preview If the object passed to `ngOutletContext` has an `$implicit` property this can be made available by just `let-xxx` and then `xxx` gets the value of the `$implicit` property.

Comment: Doesn't appear to know what `option` is though if you do this https://plnkr.co/edit/OlFCMASbWGCo7jwhEc3N?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out what you try to accomplish exactly. The template (A) is the one passed to `comp` in `my-app` and acquired by `@ContentChild(TemplateRef)`. The template (B) in comp (inside `*ngFor` is just to execute `ngTemplateOutlet` that renders template A for every `option of options`. `[ngOutletContext]` then passes data to A https://plnkr.co/edit/v086bAXiBe9Qd2qTvTka?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131041/discussion-between-chrillewoodz-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: React is so much better aye

Comment: Not sure how, but your response has helped me after hours of struggle, much appreciated!