# kendo component encapsulation template/component use

Tags: angular, angular2-template, kendo-ui-angular2, angular2-ngcontent

Is is possible to transclude custom column definitions via ng-content or TemplateRef or similar?  I've been testing via Kendo UI Grid plunker available at site (http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/) as well as [Angular2 child component as data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755844/angular2-child-component-as-data/36760027#36760027) but to no avail.  I've also tried it ng-content select but also nothing.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: 
  `
    <kendo-grid [data]="Data">
    <kendo-grid-column></kendo-grid-column>
      // ??? // <ng-content kendo-grid-column></ng-content> // [object Object]
      // ??? // <kendo-grid-column ng-content></kendo-grid-column> // [object Object]
    </kendo-grid>
  `
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() Data: any;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <test-component [Data]="gridData">
          <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="120"></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name"></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" width="230"></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" width="120">
              <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled/>
              </template>
          </kendo-grid-column>
        </test-component>
    `
})
export class AppComponent { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered by @rusev in a comment prior ... this will work for me, thanks !

> The GridComponent is using `ContentChildren` to select defined columns,
>   which does not work with transclusion. A possible workaround -
>   [plnkr.co/edit/w6EgmZL5z8J6CvpjMl2h?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/w6EgmZL5z8J6CvpjMl2h?p=preview)

This is the answer as can be seen in the plunkr

```
import { Component, Input, ContentChildren, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ColumnComponent, GridComponent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

const resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve(null); //fancy setTimeout

@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: 
  `
    <kendo-grid [data]="Data">
    </kendo-grid>
  `
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() Data: any[];

  @ContentChildren(ColumnComponent) columns;
  @ViewChild(GridComponent) grid;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef ) {}
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    resolvedPromise.then(() => { 
      this.grid.columns.reset(this.columns.toArray());
    });
  }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <test-component [Data]="gridData">
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="120"></kendo-grid-column>
        </test-component>
    `
})
export class AppComponent { ... }
```

Comment: The example on plunker doesn't seem to work anymore. In my local implementation I'm getting the following error: _v.context.$implicit.resolveStatus is null. And it seems the reset is not taking into account some more complex column implementations, eg. kendoGridCellTemplate. Any more detail on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works for me. ChangeDetectorRef is not necessary. With with following code you can even have pre-defined columns in the TestComponent that are then extended by the columns in the content:

    @ContentChildren(ColumnComponent) extraColumns: any;
    @ViewChild(GridComponent) grid: any;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        resolvedPromise.then(() => {
            var existingColumns = this.grid.columns.toArray();
            existingColumns.push(this.extraColumns.toArray());
            this.grid.columns.reset(existingColumns);
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

To select the `kendo-grid-column` elements with a `ng-content`, use:

```
<ng-content select="kendo-grid-column"></ng-content>
```

See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/d3ypNAQJ1mv4T5RIi7ae?p=preview).

Comment: I think I've tried this or something like it at one point.  It doesn't seem to work.  The result there is the default behavior of the grid when no `kendo-grid-column` components are found.  If you take that out, the result is the same.  If you duplicate or remove some columns, it does not seem to affect the result.

I think it looks for the `kendo-grid-column` like a directive or as a component, thus why I've gotten `[object Object]`.

Comment: The GridComponent is using `ContentChildren` to select defined columns, which does not work with transclusion. 
A possible workaround - http://plnkr.co/edit/w6EgmZL5z8J6CvpjMl2h?p=preview