# foreach htmlelement in ng-content

Tags: angular

I wanna create a kind of container component that modifies all (parent) tags listed in ng-content.

For example all tags within this container shall be wrapped within within a bootstrap-row to define responiveness.

Is this possible. Something like

```
            <ng-content *ngFor="let tag of tags"
              <row>{{tag}}<row>
            </ng-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

`<ng-content *ngFor="..."` is pointless. It would create `tags.length` number of `<ng-content>` elements where only the first one ever takes effect.

You can achieve something like that using `<template>` and `ngForTemplate` or `ngTemplateOutlet`

See als

- [Angular2 child component as data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755844/angular2-child-component-as-data/36760027#36760027)
- [How to repeat a piece of HTML multiple times without ngFor and without another @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676593/how-to-repeat-a-piece-of-html-multiple-times-without-ngfor-and-without-another/37676946#37676946)