# Angular 2 *ngFor handles update wrong

Tags: angular, object, typescript, ngfor

I have the following Problem:
I am using this *ngFor loop:

```
<app-sector *ngFor="let subsector of sector.subsectors" [sector]="subsector"></app-sector>
```

if the Array "subsectors" looks like this:

```
var subsectors = [
    {text: 'test', title: 'test', id: 'abc'},
    {text: 'test123', title: 'test123', id: 'def'},
    {text: 'test321', title: 'test321', id: 'ghi'}
]
```

It adds 3 "app-sector"-Components as expected. Those "app-sector"-Components are being added inside an "app-sector"-Component. The parent gets his subsectors from his parent via "@Input" in my "app-component".

This is how the HTML-Structure looks like:

```
<app-root>
    <app-sector *ngIf="playlist" [sector]="playlist">
        <app-sector *ngFor="let subsector of sector.subsectors" [sector]="subsector"></app-sector>
    </app-sector>
</app-root>
```

**Now here is where the Problem starts:**
When I update the subsectors like this:

```
//Add new subsectors
this.subsectors.push({text: 'Blah', title: 'Blah', id: '123'});
this.subsectors.push({text: 'Blah123', title: 'Blah123', id: '456'});
this.subsectors.push({text: 'Blah321', title: 'Blah321', id: '789'});

//Remove old subsectors
this.subsectors.splice(2, 1);
this.subsectors.splice(1, 1);
this.subsectors.splice(0, 1);
```

The *ngFor doesn't create new Components and only destroys a few. I can't really see a pattern. It seems to decide randomly if it destroys or creates new Components.

**Here is what i've tried sofar:**
Use trackBy. I added a trackBy filter which returned the "id" property but it didn't change anything. Here is how:

```
<app-sector *ngFor="let subsector of sector.subsectors; trackBy:identify;" [sector]="subsector"></app-sector>

identify(index,item){
    return item.id;
}
```

then i tried some Tricks i've seen while researching this issue, like using slice instead of splice. Or in the Parent i tried to do this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if(this.sector['subsectors']) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('spliced subsectores for reinitialization');
            this.sector['subsectors'] = this.sector['subsectors'].slice();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me! Please ask me in the comments if you need any further information to help me :)

kind regards.

Comment: In the *ngFor you iterate over sector.subsectors, but in the code you modify this.subsectors. Maybe i have overlooked something, but this looks peculiar to me.

Comment: it is because i update the subsectors inside the "sector" class :) this = sector

Comment: Okay. I don't quite get how you put a list of app-sectors inside another app-sector? I have never seen that done before and cannot figure out how that works?

Comment: well "app-sector" is a component in my app... And i simply put that component inside that component if this sector has some subsectors in it... The Component gets an object called "sector". This may have an non-empty array "subsectors" in it. if this is the case another "app-sector" is created inside the "app-sector" and gets the sector of subsector via @Input. if this contains subsectors the same thing repeat... thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. I had to add `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` inside my `@Component({})`. It tells Angular2 to treat any input as if they're immutable. - Solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is only my two cents but I feel like this is a problem caused by [translcusion](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content)

---

What do I mean by this?

In your template you have the following structure :

```
<app-root>
    <app-sector *ngIf="playlist" [sector]="playlist">
        <app-sector *ngFor="let subsector of sector.subsectors" [sector]="subsector"></app-sector>
    </app-sector>
</app-root>
```

`<app-sector>` has contained within its body another `<app-sector>` this leaves me to assume you have used `ng-content` somwhere in the template of your `app-sector`.

I've had similar unexpected results in the past with `*ngFor` and `ng-content`.

I usually come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190188/can-an-ng-content-be-used-inside-of-an-ng-for) when googling the subject.

> Children passed by the parent can only projected once (no matter how
>   many  are there. If the  elements don't select
>   specific and different parts of the passed children using the select
>   attribute, then everything is projected to the first  with
>   the default selector (none).

This would not explain why your initial data is displayed 3 times , but its just my two cents. Hope it can help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't used "ng-content". As you can see i am passing the subsector to the child via @Input (->[sector]="subsector"). The "subsector" contains every info the Component "app-sector" needs to be displayed as expected. And there is no problem with that. The only problem is that *ngFor seems to not create new instances and only destroys some instances of "app-sector" when the Array has been updated.